# S3 fastest way to bulk update ACL of several hundred thousand objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a simple bash script I wrote to split s3 object ids and bulk update the ACL using `s3cmd`. I start a new process for each split, but it's still very slow. What's the best way to approach this?

My thought is something like `boto3` to multithread the updates, but it's essentially the same thing, so open to suggestions.

Comment: Can I ask... _Why_ do you want to bulk update ACLs? What ACL are you wanting to configure? Are you making objects Public, or Private, or granting access to a particular Canonical ID? In general, it is best to avoid using ACLs these days, so we might be able to offer an alternative way to meet your goal.

Answer (score 2):

To give advice in a general term, a larger use-case would be needed. The use case you've given is: Update the ACL of many files in S3.

To accomplish this, there is already a technical guidance in the AWS documentation for [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/updating-amazon-s3-object-acls-at-scale-with-s3-batch-operations/): Use S3 Batch Operations.

If it's a regular issue, I would suggest into separating the files into its own buckets and use bucket level security or putting files into categories (=prefixes). Then you can use bucket policies and IAM to adjust access to these files.